Как сохранить статус чекбокса (js, mozilla)
У меня есть расширение, вот код html popup:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="delete.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-choice">Delete Extra UI</div>
    <input class="page-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="auto" name="auto" value="auto" style="color: white"/>

    <label for="auto" class="page-checkbox">AutoDelete</label>
    <script src="delete.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

И js:
auto = localStorage.getItem('auto')
if(auto){
localStorage.setItem('auto', auto.checked)
var msgObj = "Clicked"

// This is executed when the hack button is clicked
browser.tabs.query({}, tabs => {
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msgObj);
    })
})
}
else{
localStorage.setItem('auto', auto.checked)
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
var msgObj = "Clicked"

// This is executed when the hack button is clicked
browser.tabs.query({}, tabs => {
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msgObj);
    })
})
})
}

Как сделать так, чтобы после скрытия окна расширения статус чекбокса сохранялся, но при этом его можно было изменить (чекбокс всегда "выключен"). Заранее спасибо.

Сохраняйте не в localStorage, а в хранилище расширения. Так можно сохранить: await browser.storage.local.set({ auto: auto.checked }) А вот так можно получить сохранённое: await browser.storage.local.get('auto')

@ΝNL993 спасибо, но тут проблема не в сохранении
